# Can you alter the sensitivity of jQuery Scrollify?

Tags: jquery-scrollify

When using an Apple Magic Mouse (where the scroll and click areas are the same), it's very easy to trigger unwanted scrolls, especially when clicking.

So, I wondered if there was any way to reduce the sensitivity of Scrollify so, for instance, the scroll only occurs if the mouse has scrolled X number of pixels?

I realise that this isn't a configuration option, I just wondered if anyone had managed to do this before? Or knew how to?